# Magento, disable Export Products from Manage products

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I need to disable the export products function of magento sites for users that will have only permission to add or manage products.

Answer (score 0):

Create Role from **System->Permission->Roles** give required permission to user create a new user from **System->Permission->Users** and assign Role to User.

Comment: Could you specify?

Comment: Please refer link http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/users-and-user-roles

Comment: yes, but there isn't a rule for export in product grid page...

Comment: Can you please post screen shot where is export in product grid?